# three.js/WebGL: faces appearing/disappearing with alpha texture

Tags: three.js, webgl

I've got an issue with two meshes, with the "top" mesh having a texture with an alpha channel. It *should* look similar to this:

[image]

And it does... about half of the time. For the rest, it looks like:

[image: Keeping an open mind, a bit too literally.]

Now, I have a good idea as to the cause. Since the faces of the two objects occupy those same places, three.js/webGL gets a little confused, and opts to simply discard those faces on the bottom object, regardless of the fact that-due to the texture with alpha channel, both faces should be drawn.

The trouble is, I've no idea how to "enlighten" it - so to speak. All of the transparency/blending/draw solutions I've run into, either deals with drawing two semi-transparent objects, object sorting, or having an alpha threshold to discard fragments on the semi-transparent object. Needless to say, none of these seem to help.

How do I "force" opaque faces to be drawn under objects with an alpha texture?

Comment: You need to provide your code in the post, so we know what you are doing, and you need to describe exactly what you have tried. A live link with a simple example would be beneficial. Update to the current version of three.js if you have not already done so.

Comment: If someone can't tell what the issue is by the information I have provided, and point me in the right direction of solving it, then they're not going to be able to help anyway.

Comment: And on that note, there was a reason why I included "webgl" in the question/tag. If the issue needed to be solved with a custom fragment shader, or someone with better knowledge of GL blend modes, and blending equations, I imagine someone who is versed in webgl would be most beneficial to my issue, would they not?